# Ducati Monster shifting gears almost impossible

Tags: motorcycle, transmission, clutch, ducati, monster

I bought a brand new Ducati Monster 797 ABS. If I just turn the key the gears are shifting very easy and no problem finding neutral. Once the engine is running it is just about impossible to shift up and so far I have not been able to find neutral. Can anyone tell me what the problem could be?

Comment: If you just bought it brand new, why not just ask the dealer? They sell these things, so they must know everything about it!

Answer (score 1):

It may just be that the clutch is sticking / dragging. But as you say it is brand new then you need to take it back to the dealer as it is under guarantee.

And while an adjustment won't necessarily invalidate your guarantee any further work could well do.

Answer (score 1):

First guess is clutch. Take is back to the dealership. It's under warranty, right? If I were you, I'd actually request that they pick it up and drop it back off when they've identified the fix. On their dime, of course.